# Matlab script for temperature in K or F

Tags: matlab

Write a script that will prompt a user for a temperature in degrees C,and then an F for fahrenheit or K for Kelvin.The script will print the corresponding temperature  in the scale specified by the user.For example the output  mght look as follows:

Enter the teperature in degrees C:29.3
Do you want K or F?F
The temperature in degrees F is 84.7

Here is my try but it doesnt run well,I would like some correction

```
% this for prompting  a user for a temp in C and
%print a temp either in K or F as specified by the user
C=input('Enter temperature in degrees C:');
%user specification
j=input('Do you want K or F?');
%error check
while j~=K || j~=F

    disp('Please enter K or F')
    j=input('Enter K or F now:');
end
if j==F
    F=9/5*C+32;
    fprintf('The temperature in degrees F is %.2f\n',F);
else
    K=C+273.15;
    fprintf('The temperature in degrees Kis %.2f\n',K);
end
```

Comment: First of all use 'elseif (j==K)' so that only by pressing K You will get the temp in K. BTW What does it mean does not run well? Post some examples

Comment: @akfaz: Sorry,I mean it doesnt run at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not have matlab right now but try this:

```
    C=input('Enter temperature in degrees C:');

% the j should be returned as string
j=input('Do you want K or F?','s');

% You should compare string j 'K' or 'F' - in Your case the K and F was some uninitialized variables 
while j~='K' && j~='F'

    disp('Please enter K or F')
    % again return string
    j=input('Enter K or F now:','s');
end
%compare to char F
if (j=='F')
    F=9/5*C+32;
    fprintf('The temperature in degrees F is %.2f\n',F);
% compare to char 'K'
elseif (j=='K')
    K=C+273.15;
    fprintf('The temperature in degrees Kis %.2f\n',K);
end
```

Comment: Thanks let me try it now by implementation

Comment: ok I found the mistake. In the while statement instead of || should be && (I updated my code)